# Ruby gsub to PHP. Change the behavior of markdown

Tags: php, ruby, regex, markdown

I am trying to change the default behavior of [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) where single line breaks are *not* converted to `<br />`.

I found that [github flavored markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/) does this, but I am having a hard time converting the rube gsub function to something similar in PHP.

The Ruby code looks like this:

```
text.gsub!(/(\A|^$\n)(^\w[^\n]*\n)(^\w[^\n]*$)+/m) do |x|
   x.gsub(/^(.+)$/, "\\1  ")
end
```

But even that I try this simple approach in PHP I see no difference

```
$text = preg_replace("/^(.+)$/", "\\1", $text);
$text = Markdown($text);
```

Any help in the conversion from Ruby to PHP will be highly appreciated.

PS. No need for discussion of the behavior in general here, please see the meta question [should the markdown renderer treat a single line break as br](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26011/should-the-markdown-renderer-treat-a-single-line-break-as-br)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing two things in your attempt to translate the Ruby code:

1. The inner regex is inside a Ruby block – [`gsub!` calls it once for every match of its regex parameter](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-gsub-21), wih the match passed as `x`. Note the outer regex is a multiline one (as denoted by the final `m`).
2. The inner regex inserts two spaces before the matched line breaks – [the Markdown processor then converts these to `<br />` tags](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p). Your regex just replaces its match by … itself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What I am after is really a PHP equivalent to the do |X| part. Can I find a PHP function that can do the same trick?

Comment: @PeterJensen: in this specific case, the block is just an elegant way to iterate over all matches, so if PHP has a function that creates an array of captures from a regex, you could use that in a loop and should get similar results. I can’t help you there, though, as I don’t know any PHP…

Answer (score 0):

After further research I have found this preg_replace to be the most efficient PHP equivalent to the ruby code:

```
preg_replace( "/^(\w[^\r\n]*)(?=\r?\n\w.*$)/m", "\\1  ", $text );
```