# PHP DropboxClient accessing metadata with space in path

Tags: php, dropbox-php

IM having trouble accessing the ->metadata of a path when the path has a space in one of the folder names.  So if the path is /CLIENT/FOLDER NAME then the metadata call returns 401.  I am encoding the path parameter like so:

```
$path = str_replace('%2F', '/', rawurlencode($path));
```

which adds %20 for spaces.  If i go into dropbox and change the "FOLDER NAME" to "FOLDER-NAME" everything goes through just fine.  Is there another way I should be encoding the path?

Heres more code preceding
Im drilling down into folders and passing the preceding folder path as a querystring 'path'
so the url im having problems with is "/my-hub/?path=COMM%20POLICIES"

```
   $clientpath = "/DACLIENTS/$username";//username is the current user
   $path = $clientpath;
   if(isset($_GET['path'])){
      $path .= '/'.rawurldecode($_GET['path']);
   }
   $path = rawurlencode($path);
   $path = str_replace('%2F', '/', $path);
   // List contents of directory
   if ($home = $client->metadata($path)) {
       ...
   }
```

Comment: Also i think this is enough: `$path = rawurlencode($path)` i think you don't have to do the `str_replace()`

Comment: @Rizier123, No, because you don't want to encode the /'s

Comment: What version of dropbox-php are you using? @Travis Beck

Answer (score 0):

Try using the raw space. I never had to encode spaces when I worked with the dropbox API. If you look at the metadata return. Files with spaces are written exactly as they are and there is no urlencoding.

Comment: I've tried that as well, doesnt work.  If i dont encode the path, I get an exception.

Comment: What is the exception? Can you post more code - you show how you are replacing the string, but you don't show exactly what call is creating the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
gsub("%2F","/",curlEscape($path)) <-- But this is rails.
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616588/accessing-dropbox-files-with-spaces-in-path-name-using-the-api)

Here is php [curl_escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-escape.php)

gsub is similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835096/ruby-gsub-to-php-change-the-behavior-of-markdown)

```
preg_replace( "/^(\w[^\r\n]*)(?=\r?\n\w.*$)/m", "\\1  ", $text );
```

One solution was to edit the headers within the files

The problem comes from the filename format/encoding in the header of the file sent. The fix is to rawurldecode the filename in the header.

https://code.google.com/p/dropbox-php/issues/detail?id=13

PS - the path names are stored as bytes

https://code.google.com/p/dropbox-php/issues/detail?id=10